# Meteor build command stuck on "Initializing"

Tags: build, meteor

So , i have built a meteor app added some cordova plugins such as camera and so on.
now im trying to build the app also for android (apk).
here's what iv done:

```
meteor build /android --debug
```

but the terminal is stuck on "Initializing Cordova plugins..." for the past 6 hours. (added image [image])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same issue on my mac and fixed it by deleting everything below `YourApp/.meteor/local`.
(so folders `build, cordova-build, db` were deleted). Afterwards a `meteor run ios` or `meteor run android` should recreate all files.